# calculate total grouped by due date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to do two things with three ranges.
The ranges are :

1. loan amounts column
2. dates column
3. days past due column.

I need a formula that determines :

- which loan amounts fall in each month (and total the loan amounts).
- then of that group, how much in loans ($ amount) are days past due 0-29, 30-59, 60-120 and 120+.

I have formula that works with 1 and 2 above and returns dollar amount of loans in each month, but I don't know how to then return which amounts in each month are past due in the four past due ranges above.

`=SUMIFS($loanamountcolumn:$loanamountcolumn,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,">="&monthstart,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,"<="&monthend)`

This formula uses loan column as range, then looks at date column and compares to beginning of month and of month an every date that falls within each month then totals loans for that month.

Comment: Please post some sample data with desired results, without that it's difficult to imagine your situation.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need to add another condition to your SUMIFS().  This will work when the days past due is 0 - 29:

`=SUMIFS($loanamountcolumn:$loanamountcolumn,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,">="&monthstart,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,"<="&monthend,$dayspastduecolumn:$dayspastduecolumn,"<=29")`

The middle two past due ranges need two criteria, just as you have done with the datecolumn:

`=SUMIFS($loanamountcolumn:$loanamountcolumn,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,">="&monthstart,$datecolumn:$datecolumn,"<="&monthend,$dayspastduecolumn:$dayspastduecolumn,">=30",$dayspastduecolumn:$dayspastduecolumn,"<=59")`

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I was 'overthinking' it and the disconnect was that I didn't realize I could just put in the other condition vs. creating overcomplicated if/and/or statement.  THANK YOU!

Comment: The syntax is `SUMIFS(sum_range,range1,criteria1,range2,criteria2,...)`.  It looks like you're missing range2.

Comment: Or maybe not. :-)

Comment: This formula is returning zero but without Aging it calculated the amounts in a month. SUMIFS(ANALYSIS!$AL:$AL,ANALYSIS!$R:$R,">="&ANALYSIS!M5,ANALYSIS!$R:$R,"<="&ANALYSIS!N5,AGING!$P:$P,">="&AGING!P7,AGING!$Q:Q,"<="&AGING!Q7)   (ANALYSIS is one tab, AGING is the other tab)

Comment: So AL:AL is amount column, R:R is month date column, M5 is beginning of month, N5 is end of month, P:P and Q:Q are days past due (1-29, 30-59, etc.)

Comment: You mean P has actual days past due, but they're all <29? And in Q they're between 30-59?

Comment: Column P has 0, 1, 30, 60, 121+  Column Q has 29, 59, 120.

Comment: Which column has the actual days past due for each loan? That should be range3.

Comment: oh brother I think I get it now (famous last words).  There is another column that just has days past due.  Missing criteria I think.  Column BE:BE has days past due.  So forgot that one, then after that I need to know of those days which fall between the past due day ranges - WORKING ON NEW FORMULA NOW

Comment: I think if you change the $P:$P and $Q:$Q to $BE:$BE, you'll be good.

Comment: SUMIFS(ANALYSIS!$AL:$AL,ANALYSIS!$R:$R,">="&ANALYSIS!M5,"<="&ANALYSIS!N5,ANALYSIS!$BE:$BE,">="&AGING!P7,ANALYSIS!$BE:BE,"<="&AGING!Q7) said not enough arguments

Comment: You have sum_range,range1,criteria1,criteria2,range3,criteria3,range4,criteria4.  What's missing?

Comment: I have sumrange(AL:AL), range1(R:R), c1, c2, range2(BE:BE),c1,c2 ?

Comment: I figured out!  Reread your question.  I forgot to add range1(R:R) before c2.  Thank you!